# How to modify a macro to autofill a range with specific cell content?

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofill

I'm trying to automate a report into a layout the boss wants it in, I have it taken out the sales program and am adding a 1-30, 31-60, 61+ date range for sales, I have added a formula to column S,T,U with this '=IF(R4="","",IF($A4=1,IF(AND($P4<=30),$R4,0),"autosum")) changing the $P4<= value for the different number of days

I then select S:U copy and paste as values to remove the formulas, but what I am having an issue with is I need to autofill the contents from R to S:U that has autosum as the cell content

I am hoping for a macro recommendation as the report has thousands of lines, I am trying to search for autosum, use activecell.offset(0,-1) then autofill.  But I am having an issue with the range to fill.

This is the current macro that stops working after application.cutcopymode=false with an application-defined error message.

```
Sub autosum()
'
' autosum Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="autosum", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R7:U7"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("R7:U7").Select
End Sub
```

any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried with activecell.range(r:u), but after this point I am out of my depth with modifying macros.

Comment: The description of the problem is not satisfactory, rather difficult to understand like solving a puzzle. Could you show 4 lines from the sheet (with a photo) so that there is an immediate perception of what you are describing. You can correct the question by removing unnecessary information and describing the problem more clearly.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ here is a before and after, I am wanting to have all the lines that have autosum be what is in column R dragged across to fill S, T and U. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/4000/3hXIRZ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' ALL THE CODE IN THE SHEET'S MODULE
Option Explicit

Private Sub BT_FIND_AND_COPY_Click()
   Call fillAutosums
End Sub

' We have to scan ONLY column S and when find a cell with "autosum"
' get the cell on the left => R, and autofill included R four cells on the right => R,S,T,U
Private Sub fillAutosums()
   Dim r As Range, frow As Long, lastFrow As Long, curRow As Long
   Dim firstCell As String, lastCell As String, lastRow As Long
   
   ' find the last used row of the sheet
   lastRow = Me.UsedRange.rows.CountLarge
   firstCell = "S1"
   lastCell = "S" & lastRow
   ' frow and lastFrow are initially equal to 0
   On Error GoTo Lexit
   Do
      frow = WorksheetFunction.Match("autosum", Me.Range(firstCell & ":" & lastCell), 0)
      ' If we are here something from Match will have been found, otherwise
      ' there would have been fired an error
      ' we found a cell with "autosum"
      ' the row is relative to the range use in Match. To calculate the
      ' row in sheet add the last found row
      curRow = frow + lastFrow
      ' get in r the cell on the left R...
      Set r = Me.Range("R" & curRow)
      ' autofill form r to => resizing r to include S,T,U
      r.AutoFill Destination:=r.Resize(1, 4), Type:=xlFillDefault
      ' if the found row is the last of used range => no more work to do
      If frow >= lastRow Then Exit Do
      ' the next Match to begin from the next row => row after curRow
      firstCell = "S" & (curRow + 1)
      ' make the last found row equal to this found row
      lastFrow = curRow
   Loop
Lexit:
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[image]

Showing Formulas Before and after AutoFill

Comment: Thank you, your pictures look exactly like what I want to have happen, Please be patient with me, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I keep receiving a Visual Basics error that says "Compile Error: invalid Use of Me Keyword" and it highlights "Private Sub fillAutosums()" and "Me " in "lastRow = Me.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge"  I have tried starting fresh, deleting the modules, seperating the modules, adding it to my original macro attempt above and having it be on it's own.

Comment: At begining of the post i wrote: ALL THE CODE IN THE SHEET'S MODULE, so copy all the code in the module of the sheet NO IN A MODULE in folder Modules. In project explorer double click on the desired sheet to open the module for that sheet.

Comment: Hello, I have tried to get this to work multiple times, I keep having the same issue, it works properly on the first data set, and then on the following it enters a weird loop and just fills the second set but shows what is in the picture but flashing with the autosum working but then showing the sum of the first column, it is the same thing that happens on the actual sheet I am trying to get it to work in and the test sheet from the pic I made that had 6 data sets. 
Not sure if I am misunderstanding something still, your thanks for help. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/9309/9ITdPm.jpg

Comment: @Josh B YOU ARE RIGHT. I tested the code with only two blocks... Reading your comment I defined more blocks and found an error in the line lastFrow = fRow instead of lastFrow = curRow which is correct. I have fixed the line in the code. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried this on an freshly run sheet and it does exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you again!